# MVC 3 - How to know if query returns 0 rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Probably pretty easy, but I can't get it sorted out. I want to redirect the user to an error page if the requested id doesn't exist in the database. My code:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {

        DetailsAdViewModel DAVM = new DetailsAdViewModel();
        DAVM.Ad = db.Ads.Include("Images").Where(a => a.AdId == id).First();
        DAVM.FirstImage = db.Images.Where(a => a.AdId == id).OrderBy(a => a.ImageId).Take(1);

        // make sure the ad isn't deleted or that it really exists
        if (DAVM.Ad == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Error", new { errorCode = "adDeleted" });
        }

        return View(DAVM);
    }
```

This doesn't work, and there is an server error if I enter a false id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.First()`. This will return null if not record is found instead of throwing an exception:

```
DAVM.Ad = db.Ads.Include("Images").FirstOrDefault(a => a.AdId == id);
```

Now you can check if `DAVM.Ad` is null:

```
if (DAVM.Ad == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Error", new { errorCode = "adDeleted" });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, even better solution! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {

```
        if (db.Ads.Any(a => a.AdId == id))
        {
            DetailsAdViewModel DAVM = new DetailsAdViewModel();
            DAVM.Ad = db.Ads.Include("Images").Where(a => a.AdId == id).First();
            DAVM.FirstImage = db.Images.Where(a => a.AdId == id).OrderBy(a => a.ImageId).Take(1);

            return View(DAVM);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Error", new { errorCode = "adDeleted" });
        }
    }
```